# SVG clip-path animation bug in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm new at animating SVGs with CSS and I'm trying to create a "blinking eye" effect. This is what I've managed to do:

https://codepen.io/pablo-m/pen/jOGeMpJ.

(Edit 3: Code added)

`SVG`

```
<svg id="composicion" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 571.8 761.82">
  <g id="Ojito">
    <rect x="190.37" y="288.55" width="192.7" height="91.76" fill="#606060" />
    <ellipse id="outer-eye" cx="292.3" cy="335.43" rx="44.72" ry="30.01" fill="#3caa56" />
    <circle id="inner-eye" cx="291.69" cy="334.82" r="18.38" fill="#efefef" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

`SCSS`

```
#composicion {
  #Ojito {
    @keyframes inner-eye-blink {
      0%,
      82%,
      95%,
      100% {
        clip-path: ellipse(75% 55%);
      }
      90% {
        clip-path: ellipse(75% 0);
      }
    }

    @keyframes outer-eye-blink {
      0%,
      80%,
      100% {
        ry: 30.01px;
      }
      90% {
        ry: 1px;
      }
    }

    & #outer-eye {
      animation: outer-eye-blink 8s ease infinite;
    }

    & #inner-eye {
      animation: inner-eye-blink 8s infinite;
    }
  }
}
```

The animation works great on Firefox v95.0.2 and Safari v15.1. However, on Chrome/Chromium v97.0.4692.71 (as of today, the latest version) it does not. It looks like, whenever I apply a `clip-path` with css the white `circle` dissapears. I also noticed that this behaviour does not happen on Chrome/Chromium v96.0.4664.93. Am I doing something wrong or did something change in the latest version of Chrome/Chromium? Edit: If I did everything correctly, does anyone know a workaround?

This is my first question in SO, so please let me know if I missed any detail.

Thanks!

Edit: I have looked at Chromium's bug tracker but I've not found any relevant issues there.

Edit 2: [Chromium bug reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1286412)

Comment: Chromium's bugtracker [is here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: ...and it's showing nothing relvant so far. I can confirm `clip-path: ellipse(...)` seems not to work in v97.You did nothing wrong. Are you interested in finding a workaround, or does that answer your question? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: thanks for confirming the issue, @ccprog! yes, a workaround would be great! i've edited the question.

@RobertLongson I looked at Chromium's bug tracker before posting the question, but I didn't find anything related :/

Comment: Sounds like you need to raise a new issue in that bugtracker then.

Comment: @RobertLongson will do!

Comment: Code needs to be inside the question itself not behind a link.

Comment: thanks @gre_gor. will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a Chrome bug indeed. However, I managed to find a workaround which solves the issue: https://codepen.io/pablo-m/pen/WNZYeoB

`SCSS`

```
#composicion {
  #Ojito {
    @keyframes inner-eye-move {
      0%,
      5%,
      20%,
      25%,
      40%,
      45%,
      50%,
      60%,
      65%,
      80%,
      85%,
      100% {
        cx: 291.69px;
        cy: 334.82px;
      }
      10%,
      15% {
        cx: 273.69px;
        cy: 328.82px;
      }
      30%,
      35% {
        cx: 291.69px;
        cy: 342.82px;
      }
      70%,
      75% {
        cx: 310.69px;
        cy: 328.82px;
      }
      90%,
      95% {
        cx: 307.69px;
        cy: 338.82px;
      }
    }

    @keyframes outer-eye-blink {
      0%,
      80%,
      100% {
        ry: 30.01px;
      }
      90% {
        ry: 1px;
      }
    }

    & .outer-eye {
      animation: outer-eye-blink 8s ease infinite;
    }

    & #inner-eye {
      clip-path: url(#eyeClip);
      animation: inner-eye-move 50s ease infinite;
    }
  }
}
```

`SVG`

```
<svg id="composicion" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 571.8 761.82">
  <g id="Ojito">
    <rect x="190.37" y="288.55" width="192.7" height="91.76" fill="#606060" />
    <clipPath id="eyeClip">
      <ellipse class="outer-eye" cx="292.3" cy="335.43" rx="44.72" ry="30.01" />
    </clipPath>
    <ellipse class="outer-eye" cx="292.3" cy="335.43" rx="44.72" ry="30.01" fill="#3caa56" />
    <circle id="inner-eye" cx="291.69" cy="334.82" r="18.38" fill="#efefef" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'll edit my question and answer when I post the bug on the Chrome bug tracker.

Edit: [Chromium bug reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1286412)

Edit 2: For another great workaround, please look at [@chrwahl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673318/17904888)

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this it is a good idea to use either a clip-path or a mask because you have more elements that need to be animated/masked off. In this example I chose CSS clip-path because you started off with the animation in CSS.

My example works fine in Chrome 97 as I see it.

Another option would be to use [SVG animation with SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL). I would expect it to work in Chrome as well. In some cases it is more flexible then mask or clip-path in CSS.

I used [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) for constructing the path.

```css
@keyframes eye-blink {
  0%,
  100% {
    clip-path: path('M 3 5 C 6 6 9 7 13 5 C 9 2 6 3 3 5');
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: path('M 3 5 C 6 5 9 5 13 5 C 9 5 6 5 3 5');
  }
}

#Ojito g {
  clip-path: path('M 3 5 C 6 6 9 7 13 5 C 9 2 6 3 3 5');
  animation: eye-blink 4s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg id="composicion" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 10" width="400">
  <g id="Ojito">
    <rect width="16" height="10" fill="#606060" />
    <g>
      <rect width="16" height="10" fill="white" />
      <circle id="inner-eye" cx="8" cy="4.8" r="2" fill="#333" />
      <circle id="inner-eye" cx="8" cy="4.8" r="1.2" fill="black" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: the animation looks amazing!
i didn't know about [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/), looks like a great tool!
thank you very much!!!